# Google Cloud Vision not recognizing Tibetan Characters

Tags: cloud, vision, text-recognition

Hi i want to recognize Tibetan text from image, but it extracts garbage text..
Is there a way to fix this issue? [this is image i used to extract text on that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POSXY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Tibetan is still under development. See the full list of supported languages [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages).

There are other OCRs that support Tibetan though. Try e.g. [Tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html).

Comment: but google cloud vision works fine previously for Tibetan language. but now it shows wrong garbage text. working one become down.. now not working.. so i thing some done changes which made totally unusable for that language ..